# MSBuild uses wrong framework version

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm crafting an MSBuild file and within it I need to use Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll, problem is MSBuild cant find this file... and it can't find it because MSBuildToolsPath is pointing at the wrong version of the .Net framework... Why? How do I stop this happening? Why ISNT this test using the version of MSBuild that it is compiled with?

I have the following simple targets file (which I've saved as MSBuildTest.targets) to demonstrate the issue I am seeing

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Default">
        <Message Text="$(MSBuildToolsPath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

> C:\Test> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild MSBuildTest.targets
>
> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3062.0
>   [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Build started 12/08/2018 17:46:07.
>   Project "MSBuildTest.targets" on node 1 (default targets).
>   Default:
>
> **C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727**
>
> Done Building Project "MSBuildTest.targets" (default targets).
>
> Build succeeded.
>       0 Warning(s)
>      0 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07

So why is MSBuildToolsPath pointing at **v2.0.50727** when I'm executing with MSBuild **v4.0.30319** ??

I did do a little digging, under registry editor, I have this key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0

... with this value...

> MSBuildToolsPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\

This is driving me mad, any help??

Comment: ”MSBuild.targets“ is not something on everyone's machine. If you want an answer, make it reproducible everywhere.

Comment: I provided the full contents of "MSBuild.targets" in the question. I will amend to make it clear that this is the only file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full contents of MSBuildTest.targets was posted in the question.

Amending the targets file and setting **ToolsVersion="4.0"** as follows results in the correct output as seen below

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <Target Name="Default">
        <Message Text="$(MSBuildToolsPath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3062.0
>   [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Build started 17/08/2018 12:17:06.
>   Project "C:\test\MSBuildTest.targets" on node 1 (default targets).
>   Default:
>
> **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**
>
> Done Building Project "C:\test\MSBuildTest.targets" (default targets).

I think the problem is, when building with a particular version of MSBuild I expected the MSBuildToolsPath to be set according to the version of MSBuild that I was using.